# List contains duplicate Persons

Tags: vb.net

Please see the code below:

```
Public Function ExecuteDynamicQuery(ByVal strSQL As String, ByVal list As List(Of clsType), ByVal tyType As clsType) As List(Of clsType) Implements IGenie.ExecuteDynamicQuery
            Dim objParameterValues As New clsParameterValues
            Dim iConnectionBLL As iConnectionBLL
            Dim objCon As DbConnection
            Dim objDR As DbDataReader
            Dim paramValues() As DbParameter
            objParameterValues = New clsParameterValues
            iConnectionBLL = New clsConnectionBLL()
            objCon = iConnectionBLL.getDatabaseTypeByDescription("Genie2")
            Using objCon
                paramValues = objParameterValues.getParameterValues
                objDR = clsDatabaseHelper.ExecuteReader(objCon, CommandType.Text, strSQL, paramValues)
                Do While objDR.Read
                    Dim tyType2 As clsType = tyType
                    tyType.PopulateDataReader(objDR)
                    list.Add(tyType2)
                Loop
                objDR.Close()
                Return list
            End Using
        End Function
```

An SQL statement is passed to the function along with clsType (the base type).  A list of types is returned e.g. a list of Persons.  For example, in this case strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Persons".  A list of 500 persons is returned but they are all the same person (the last person added to the list).  I realise this is because the list is referncing the same object for each entry.  How do I change this?

Comment: @Steven Doggart, No, Person is a data transfer object that inherits from clsType i.e. all types inherit from clsType.

Comment: This code abuses the helper class, because it does not allow you to correctly handle query parameters. It forces you to write code that will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks, and is therefore practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn, could you explain what you mean by: "does not allow you to correctly handle query parameters".

Comment: Yes. The code as written only deals with an sql string. The only way to put parameter data into that method is to use string concatenation. This **will** result in your app getting hacked.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, Did you miss where he's passing the `paramValues` to the helper method?

Comment: @Steven Doggart.  You are correct.  The SQL passed would look something like this: "select * from person where id=@ID".  ObjParameterValues encapsulates the generation of the parameters.

Comment: @StevenDoggart No, I saw that. The problem is that he never puts any data into `paramValues`. The only assignment comes from the default instance of a new `clsParameterValues` class. It's going to be an empty array every time, no matter what he sends to the function.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, granted.  I assumed that he either left some part out of the example or that class was grabbing the values out of global space--another possible flaw :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a situation where making the method generic would be useful.  For instance:

```
Public Function MyGenericMethod(Of T As New)() As List(Of T)
    Dim results As New List(Of T)()
    For i As Integer = 0 To 9
        Dim item As New T()
        ' Populate item ...
        results.Add(item)
    Next
    Return results
End Function
```

For what it's worth, though, I see people trying do this kind of thing often, and it never sits well with me.  I'm always the first one in line to suggest that common code should be encapsulated and not duplicated all over the place, but, I've never been convinced that creating some sort of data access layer that encapsulates the calls to ADO, but *doesn't* also encapsulate the SQL, is a good idea.

Consider for a moment that ADO, is in-and-of-itself an encapsulation of that part of the data-access layer.  Sure, it can take a few more lines of code than you might like to execute a simple SQL command, but that extra complexity is there for a reason.  It's necessary in order to support all of the features of the data source.  If you try to simplify it, inevitably, you will one day need to use some other feature of the data source, but it won't be supported by your simplified interface.  In my opinion, each data access method should use all of the necessary ADO objects directly rather than trying to some how create some common methods to do that.  Yes, that does mean that many of your data access methods will be very similar in structure, but I think you'll be happier in the long run.

Comment: This is a definite improvement over the OPs function design, but part of the problem is that the OP is implementing an interface, and so in this case it's probably better to keep the same function signature.

Comment: True, if you couldn't also make the interface generic, then you'd have to resort to reflection to instantiate the objects.  Or... rethink the design :)

Comment: Plus one for the added ending paragraph. SQL code definitely belongs as part of the data access. Trying to separate that away will lead to pain.

Comment: Thanks.  If I made the method generic then I would have to use reflection to populate the return object e.g. Person, Vehicle, Order etc i.e. map the database field values to the appropriate object using Reflection.  Do you agree? +1.

Comment: Correct. There would be no way for you to know what properties arre on the data object except via reflection.  At that point, you might as well just return a plain old DataSet, DataTable, or DataRow.

Answer (score 1):

I've reduced your original code. The following sample is functionally equivalent to what you posted. Without knowing more about your types, it will hard to give you anything more than this, but maybe the reduction will make the code clear enough for you to spot a solution:

```
Public Function ExecuteDynamicQuery(ByVal sql As String, ByVal list As List(Of clsType), ByVal type As clsType) As List(Of clsType) Implements IGenie.ExecuteDynamicQuery
    Dim paramValues() As DbParameter = New clsParameterValues().getParameterValues()
    Using conn As DbConnection = iConnectionBLL.getDatabaseTypeByDescription("Genie2"), _
          rdr  As DbDataReader = clsDatabaseHelper.ExecuteReader(conn, CommandType.Text, sql, paramValues)

        While rdr.Read()
            type.PopulateDataReader(rdr)
            list.Add(type)
        End While

        Return list
    End Using           
End Function
```

There are a few additional bits of advice I can give you:

1. You **must** have some way to accept parameter information for your query that is separate from the query itself. The `ExecuteReader()` method that you call supports this, but you only ever pass it an empty array. Fix this, or you **will** get hacked.
2. A implementation that uses Generics (as posted in another answer) would be much simpler and cleaner. The Genie interface you're relying doesn't seem to be adding much value. You'll likely do better starting over with a system that understands generics.
3. The problem of re-using the same object over and over can be fixed by creating a new object inside the loop. As written, the only way to do that is with a `New clsType` (and it seems you may have Option Strict Off, such that this could blow up on you at run time), through some messy reflection code, a switch to using generics as suggested in #2, or a by accepting a `Func(Of clsType)` delegate that can build the new object for you.